# "Отчётная Конференция". Конференция с большой буквы или маленькой?

Tags: прописная-строчная

Отчётная Конференция. В данном словосочетании конференция с большой или маленькой буквы пишется?

Answer (score 1):

С маленькой. С большой бы писалось разве что как первое слово в официальном названии мероприятия.

Answer (score 0):

Если Компания с Продуктом для дорогих Клиентов - то Отчётная Конференция. Если компания - то отчётная конференция (неуникальное, регулярное событие)